# Space complexity of split() function in python

Tags: python, split, space-complexity

I have a question if whether the following code is executed in place or has extra space complexity. Given that sentence was a string initially. Thanks appreciate the help

`sentence = "hello world"`

`sentence = sentence.split()`

Comment: The source is a string, the result is a list. How could this be executed in-place?

Comment: @GPhilo The substrings in the list could use the same backing array as the original immutable string.

Comment: python strings are basically immutable, there is no action that happens "in place" on them, whatever you do will always create another string (or in your case, another object entirely - a list)

Comment: @tobias_k that's not what in-place means, though.

Comment: No definite answer, but after splitting a very, very long string (~5GB) the memory-comsumption of my interactive Python session (IPython 5.5 using Python 3.6.8) about doubled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python strings are immutable objects, which means that they cannot change at all "in-place". All actions on them essentially take up new memory space, and hopefully, the old unused ones are deleted by python's garbage collecting process (if there are no more references to those objects). One method to see it for yourself is this:

```
>>> a = 'hello world'
>>> id(a)
1838856511920
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
1838856511920
>>> a += '!'
>>> id(a)
1838856512944
>>> id(b)
1838856511920
```

As you can see, when `b` and `a` are referring to the same underlying objects, their `id` in memory is the same, but as soon as one of them changes, it now has a new `id` - a new space in memory. The object that was left unchanged (`b`) still has the same place-id.

To check it in your example:

```
>>> sentence = "hello world"
>>> id(sentence)
1838856521584
>>> sentence = sentence.split()
>>> id(sentence)
1838853280840
```

We can once again see that those objects are not taking the same memory. We can further explore just how much space they take up:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sentence = "hello world"
>>> sys.getsizeof(sentence)
60
>>> sentence = sentence.split()
>>> sys.getsizeof(sentence)
160
```

Comment: While this is all true, I thing you are taking the question too literally, or focussing to much on the "in-place" wording.

Comment: @tobias_k you might be right which is why I added the size comparison at the end, because maybe that's the real important factor for him. Either way, your experiment demonstrates both aspects as well

Comment: I don't think the use of `sys.getsizeof` is correct here, as it does not reflect the actual additionally needed memory. See my example.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` doesn't prove anything by itself, that's true, but it is a measure of how much memory space is taken, regadless of the reason. It isn't exact because the implementation of `__sizeof__ ` in the actual objects is the result being shown here. Your actual tests of size in memory are better in that regard, I agree

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, the operation can not be "in-place", as that would mean within the same data structure, but you are abviously creating a new data structure (a list) from the string. I will assume that your actual question was whether the substrings returned by `split` will use the same backing array of characters as the original immutable string.<sup>1)</sup>

A quick experiment seems to suggest that they do not.

```
In [1]: s = (("A" * 100000) + " ") * 50000

In [2]: len(s)
Out[2]: 5000050000

In [3]: l = s.split()
```

After the first step, `top` shows that the `ipython` process uses ~30% of my memory, and after the `split` it uses ~60%, so the backing array, taking up the bulk of the memory, is not reused. Of course, this may be implementation specific. I was using IPython 5.5.0 (based on Python 3.6.8), but get the same result with Python 2.7.15, too. This also seems to apply to string slicing.

<sup>1)</sup> Precisely because the strings are immutable this would be possible, and to the best of my knowledge other languages, like Java, do this, although I can currently not test it.)

---

Note: The use of `sys.getsizeof` is a bit misleading here, as that seems to measures only the size of the actual data structure, not the elements contained therein.

```
In [4]: sys.getsizeof(s)
Out[4]: 5000050049

In [5]: sys.getsizeof(l)
Out[5]: 433816
```

According to that, the list takes up only a fraction of the space of the original splitted string, but as noted above, the actual memory consumption doubled.

Comment: I don't think this can be implementation specific because the definition of strings in python is immutable objects. Other than that, good demo!

Comment: @OferSadan But precisely _because_ they are immutable they _could_ in fact share the same backing array (and I would have assumed them to do so). Not sure, but I think Java e.g. does that.

Comment: cpython `str.split()` ends up calling the C function [`split_whitespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L54).  which has an optimisation where the same backing is indeed used if the string wasn't split, but otherwise always allocates new strings for each span